# Pie in cartesian coordinates

Tags: javascript, math

Below is the code to generate a "filled" circle (a disk) in cartesian coordinates using the well known formula:

(x - j)<sup>2</sup> + (y - k)<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>

where j & k are the coordinates of the center and r the radius.

It works well but now I would like to generate only a sector, a pie of the disk but still using the cartesian coordinates. Any clue on how this can be achieved?

```
    for(var scanx=x-radius; scanx<x+radius; scanx+=1) {            
        // out of extend
        if(scanx<0 || scanx>params.width){
            continue;
        }
        for(var scany=y-radius; scany<y+radius; scany+=1) {

            if(scany<0 || scany>params.height) {
              continue;
            }                  

            var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((scanx-x), 2)+Math.pow((scany-y), 2));

            if(dist > radius) {
                continue;
            } else {
                var v = data - params.step * Math.pow(dist, degree);
                var id = scanx+scany*params.width;
                if(value[id]){
                   value[id] = Math.max(value[id], v); 
                } else {
                    value[id] = v;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Off-topic: calculating square roots is slow. Better calculate `radius*radius` before the loop, and compare it to `scanx*(scanx-2*x)+x*x+scany*(scany-2*y)+y*y` (=`dist*dist`) at each iteration. Also note `x*x` is faster than `Math.pow(x,2)`, because function calls are slow.

Comment: You could always ask wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+equation+of+arc

Comment: Moreover, instead of looping through useless values, better improve your loop to `for(var scanx=Math.max(x-radius,0), untilx=Math.min(x+radius,params.width); scanx<untilx; ++scanx)`, and get rid of `if(scanx<0 || scanx>params.width)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a segment of the curve by defining the section of the x and y axes you want to output.

So if you wanted to print the first quadrant of the circle, you would limit your "x" for-loop to between `0` and `x+radius`, and your "y" for-loop to between `0` and `y+radius`.

If you are looking for output based on starting angle `θ1` and final angle `θ2` you would need to translate those to from polar to Cartesian coordinates using:

```
x1 = r × cos( θ1 ); y1 = r × sin( θ1 ); 
x2 = r × cos( θ2 ); y2 = r × sin( θ2 );
```

then use the values x1, x2 as your x for-loop bounds and y1 and y2 as your y for-loop bounds.

**One caveat to using this approach:**

If your arc distance is more than 45 degrees, you will need to break it up into segments from start to nearest axis and get the maximum coordinate value. Or you could loop through angle steps and print out x-y coordinates from the polar-cartesian conversion above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyfN9/)